# Attach custom iam policy to iam role

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to deal with some terraform scripts that are held across different git repo's.
One of the repo's is used for provisioning eks infrastructure and the other is to hold generic tf scripts.

In the generic repo, I've created a custom iam policy. I want this to be attached to the iam role when the eks infrastructure repo is created. Is there a way to do this?

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "eks-worker-node-data-access" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/base-data-capture"
  role       = "${module.eks-control-plane.worker_node_role_name}"
}
```

The policy arn field is set to the name of the policy that would be created, however this fails as it hasn't been imported...

What I'd like to do is something like

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "eks-worker-node-data-access" {
 source = "my-git-repo.policy"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/base-data-capture"
  role       = "${module.eks-control-plane.worker_node_role_name}"
}
```

I suppose the obvious answer would be to just have the policy created in the same tf folder, but all other policies have been created in the generic repo.

Comment: Where do you store the state for the generic repo? A `terraform_remote_state` block would give you access across the repos. Another option would be to declare a module whose source is the directory in other repo and hard-code the role name as an output.

Comment: Instead of `resource` why don't you use `data` to retrieve what was created by the "other" repo ... I've done that in the past with great success, one project creates base infrastructure such as network, and others specialize in other components, the build are faster that way